# Grails - Retrieve an object from another tenant - erro import

Tags: grails

I have a system in grails, already running on a server, and we use tenant solutions to distinguish the branches of the corporation, but now I need to recover information from one branch to another.

The point is when I make the following query in my model:

```
          def isThisFilial = true
          vol.recoversExpedition().eachWithIndex { row, index ->
            log.debug "* Id ${row.id} Code ${row.code} Clint {row.client}"
            def expedition = Expedition.findByCodigo(row.codigo)
            if(!expedition){
              log.info "*expedition is in another subsidiary"
              isThisFilial = false
              expedition = Tenants.withoutId{Expedition.findByCode(row.code)}
             }
          }
```

If my expedition was issued by a branch this find does not return anything to me, after all it was thus the initial architecture for the branch offices not to fill information of each other.

I tried to use the `Tenants.withoutId` function but by the time I add the `import grails.gorm.multitenancy.Tenants` this is pointing me to the following error:

> | Error Compilation error: startup failed:
>   D:\GitHub\wms\wms\grails-app\domain\wms\Devolucao.groovy: 6: unable to
>   resolve c lass grails.gorm.multitenancy.Tenants  @ line 6, column 1.
>   import grails.gorm.multitenancy.Tenants    ^
>
> 1 error

I do not know if I have to do some annotation in another area or what was missing and because it is not working, I'll put my `BuildConfig.groovy` here:

```
plugins {
        //build ":tomcat:7.0.52.1"
        build ":tomcat:7.0.70"
        runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.9"

        compile ':scaffolding:2.0.3'

        runtime ":jquery:1.8.3"
        compile ':cache:1.1.1'

        runtime ':resources:1.2.8'

        compile ":cache-headers:1.1.5"
        runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
        runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0"
        runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.5"

        // framework dependencies
        compile ":mail:1.0.1"
        compile ":fields:1.4"
        compile ":runtime-logging:0.4"
        compile ":burning-image:0.5.1"
        compile ":twitter-bootstrap:2.3.2"
        compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC4"
        compile ":spring-security-rest:1.4.0.RC5", {
            excludes: 'spring-security-core'
        }

        // multitenancy
        compile ":multi-tenant-single-db:0.8.3"

        // events to implement app hooks
        compile ":platform-core:1.0.RC6"

        // Para fazer upload de imagens
        compile ":attachmentable:0.3.0"

        // calendários para campos do tipo Date
        compile ":calendar:1.2.1"

        // exportar dados para Excel
        compile ":excel-export:0.1.9", {
            excludes: 'xerces'
        } 

        // Jasper Reports
        compile ":jasper:1.11.0"

        // Export CSV
        compile ":csv:0.3.1"

        // Tests
        test ":cucumber:0.6.2"

        // Profiling
        compile ":profiler:0.5"

        //webservice SOAP
        compile ":cxf:1.1.4"
        compile ":cxf-client:2.0.3"

        //cron job
        compile ":quartz:1.0.2"

        //http-builder
        //compile ":rest:0.8"
        //compile ":rest-client-builder:2.1.1"

        //etiqueta AR
       // compile ":barcode4j:0.3"

    }
```

Comment: grails.gorm.multitenancy.Tenants seems to be provided by GORM 6.x and later.  From your hibernate version and the fact that you have a BuildConfig.groovy I'm guessing you're on grails 2.something and GORM 3?  I believe you are using an API in your code that you do not actually have available.

Comment: This is my same text in version 2.3.11 and hibernate is in version 3.6.10.9. If in this version I do not have this feature, how can I do what I need the `Tenants.withoutId` function?